# Improving TeXForm handling of fraction

Tags: latex

`TeXForm` does not always change fraction `a/b` to $\frac{a}{b}$. If the fraction was an exponent for example, it keeps it `a/b`.

Is there a way to make `TeXForm` always change fraction to correct Latex output which is $\frac{a}{b}$ regardless of where the fraction is located in the expression?

Here is an example

```
 TeXForm[3/2]
 (*   \frac{3}{2}  *)
```

But

```
 TeXForm[y^(3/2)]
 (*   y^{3/2}  *)
```

I prefer the above to be

```
 y^{\frac{3}{2}}
```

Which, for me, looks a little better when compiled.  Compare for example

$y^{3032/7}$ and $y^{\frac{3032}{7}}$

Using V 12 on windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to adjust the [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) formatting of such expressions. In order to only affect [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm), I think the most convenient approach is to modify a [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm) internal function so that its behavior is controlled by a global variable:

```
Unprotect[Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX];
Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX[e_, opts___?OptionQ] /; !TrueQ@$TeX := Block[
    {$TeX = True},
    Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX[e, opts]
]
Protect[Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX];
```

Now, give your expression a [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm) format that is conditioned on the global variable `$TeX`:

```
Unprotect[Power];
Power /: MakeBoxes[a_^b_Rational, TraditionalForm] /; TrueQ @ $TeX := MakeBoxes[
    a^Defer[b],
    TraditionalForm
]
Protect[Power];
```

Finally, you should have the desired output from [`TeXForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm):

```
TeXForm[y^(3/2)]
```

> y^{\frac{3}{2}}