# Forcing TeXForm to produce fractions using division simbol / instead of \frac

Tags: latex, traditional-form

I want to do something converse to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/204671/improving-texform-handling-of-fraction). Namely, I want to force the output of `TeXForm[]` to be always presented with a division symbol `/` instead of `\frac{}{}`.

Can one do it using `TraditionalForm` as in the answer to the question I posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add conversion rules like this:

```
Convert`TeX`ExpressionToTeX[
 a/beta,
 "BoxRules" :> Append[
   System`Convert`TeXFormDump`$GreekWords, 
   FractionBox[num_, den_, ___] :> 
    System`Convert`TeXFormDump`MakeTeX[num] <> "/" <> 
     System`Convert`TeXFormDump`MakeTeX[den]]]

(* "a/\\beta" *)
```

The problem is that `\frac` doesn't parenthesize, so it does not work on something like `a/(b+c)`.
Neither does it use `TeXForm`. If you need `TeXForm`, you have to permanently change `$GreekWords`.

```
$savedGreekWords = System`Convert`TeXFormDump`$GreekWords;
Protect[$savedGreekWords];
parenthesizeBoxes // ClearAll;
parenthesizeBoxes[boxes_RowBox] := 
  "\\left(" <> System`Convert`TeXFormDump`MakeTeX[boxes] <> "\\right)";
parenthesizeBoxes[boxes_] := System`Convert`TeXFormDump`MakeTeX[boxes];
myTeXBoxRules = 
  Join[System`Convert`TeXFormDump`$GreekWords, {FractionBox[num_, den_, ___] :>
      parenthesizeBoxes[num] <> "/" <> parenthesizeBoxes[den]}];
```

Using it with `TeXForm`:

```
System`Convert`TeXFormDump`$GreekWords = myTeXBoxRules;
a/(b + c) + (a + c)/b // TeXForm
System`Convert`TeXFormDump`$GreekWords = $savedGreekWords;

(* a/\left(b+c\right)+\left(a+c\right)/b *)
```

Comment: This is a great solution, thank you. Is it also possible to replace \left(\right) brackets with usual () brackets?

Comment: @PawełKorzeb  Sure, just change the string `"\\left("` to `"("` and similarly for the other (in `parenthesizeBoxes`). Whatever you put there will end up in the TeX form output.  Note that the parentheses won't scale if you leave off `"\\left"` and `"\\right"`. If you don't need that, then omit them. Theoretically, one could even cycle through delimiters (e.g. `()`, `[]`, `{}`) for nested parenthesization.

Comment: Unfortunately, it works only partially. In the case of consecutive brackets ```\left(\right)``` is still produced in the output

Comment: @PawełKorzeb I don't know what you mean. Other TeX rules, other than the one for fractions above, use `\left` and `\right`. The built-in rules Mathematica almost always put them in, letting TeX figure out whether the delimiters need to be increased in size. Is that what you mean? You might have to change quite a few rules, assuming none of them are hardcoded in internal functions. It would be easier to get the TeX string and remove them afterwords, if you want to remove all instances.

Answer (score 8):

It is much easier to do this directly in your latex document where you will compile the latex generated by Mathematica `TeXForm`.

Once you copy your Mathematica generated Latex to your Latex document, just add this command in the preample, which will automatically convert all `\frac{}{}` to `/`

Lets say you did

```
TeXForm[a/c + Exp[r/d]]
```

Which generates

```
\frac{a}{c}+e^{\frac{r}{d}}
```

In your Latex document load `\usepackage{nicefrac}` and renew the command `\frac` to automatically use `nicefrac`, like this

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\renewcommand{\frac}[2]{\nicefrac{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*} 
\frac{a}{c}+e^{\frac{r}{d}}
\end{align*} 
\end{document}
```

Which gives

[image]

If you change your mind later, and do not want this, just comment the `renew` command and now you will get back the original output

[image]

Comment: This is a very nice answer, thank you. However, I explicitly wanted ```TexForm[]``` to generate the expression with division signs ```/``` because the latex expressions I have are very lengthy, and I want to use ```dmath``` environment from ```breqn``` package to automatically break the line. ```\frac{}{}``` prevented ```dmath``` from automatic line breaking because of the fraction structure. Your solution indeed prints ```/``` instead, but raw code still has ```\frac```s, and line breaking with ```dmath``` still doesn't work. Can one tune this solution so it works with ```dmath```?